# Detect when an added subview's frame's origin is behind the status bar

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am adding subviews to the top of my view controllers, setting the added frame's origin's y to 0

```
aView.frame.origin.y = 0.0;
```

On one instance, the view appeared behind the status bar. This can be corrected easily by setting `origin.y = 20.0;`

Regardless of what the cause may be, how can I detect if I need to set it to 20.0 or not? In other words, how can I find out if the top of the page is behind the status bar or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can peek into window.screen.applicationFrame to see coordinates, and at UIApplication's statusBarOrientation and statusBarHidden properties. But conditionally setting your frame top to 0 or 20 isn't really the solution - you want your frames to be set up so that it does the right thing without you having to change it. 0,0 should always be the top-left visible corner of your view.

If you used the view-based application template when you created your project, nearly everything should be set up correctly - just make sure that you specify a Gray or Black status bar in your XIB.

For programmatically created view controllers that you add directly to the Window, you might need:

```
myViewController.frame = window.screen.applicationFrame;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it when I have some time to see if works for me.

Comment: It's not marked as right... but i've been stuck on this for a whole day. Turns out I also need to work on my google skills. Thanks heaps man